# How to exit the rake task when running timeout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake-task

I set a cron job to run a rake task. This task will do somethings, such as send a post request...

If timeout, process cannot finished normally. How to set a timeout time, if this time is surpassed,

then the rake task will exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'timeout'
status = Timeout::timeout(5) {
  # Something that should be interrupted if it takes too much time...
}
```